# Xcode 12. Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member 'supportedFlashModes'

Tags: xcode, xcode12

In new Xcode 12, there is an error: `Value of type 'AVCapturePhotoOutput' has no member 'supportedFlashModes'` when i try to reach https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotooutput/1648766-supportedflashmodes
Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Looks like it could have accidentally marked as private looking at this post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86810

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andy Heard [wrote](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86810):

> Our apologies. For apps using Swift 3.2 or Swift 4.0, several
> AVFoundation capture APIs (public extensions on external protocol)
> were inadvertently marked private in Xcode 9.
>
> The following AVFoundation API are temporarily unavailable:
>
> - `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces`
> - `AVCaptureDevice.supportedFlashModes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availablePhotoPixelFormatTypes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
> - `AVCapturePhotoSettings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes`
>
> As a workaround you can use the SwiftPrivate versions of these API by
> prepending each API with double underscore (`__`). For example, change
> `AVCaptureDevice.Format.supportedColorSpaces` to
> `AVCaptureDevice.Format.__supportedColorSpaces`.

Answer (score 9):

Seems to be a bug on Xcode 12, but you can workaround it using macro conditions:

```
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
guard stillImageOutput?.supportedFlashModes.contains(mode) == true else { return }
//rest of your code
#endif
```

Comment: What is the `mode` value please?

Comment: I still get the error. `backCamera.hasFlash && self.stillImageOutput.supportedFlashModes.contains(mode)`

Comment: `mode` is an `AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode` value, it's just an example.

Answer (score 0):

For the XCode 12 regression (sigh), you can use the __ version like so

```
    var flashModesSupported: [AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode] {
        #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
        return self.photoOutput.__supportedFlashModes.compactMap { AVCaptureDevice.FlashMode.init(rawValue: $0.intValue) }
        #else
        return self.photoOutput.supportedFlashModes
        #endif
    }
```

There was a report this did not trigger SPI (so, safe to submit to app store)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
let device2 = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

if (device2.supportedFlashModes.contains(.auto)){

} else {
            
}
```